# Need some help getting a table back from a query , for future use on my own database

Tags: mysql, sql

Users

```
User ID Site ID Name
1   1   Arthur
2   1   Aaron
2   2   Brett
```

Transactions

```
Transaction ID  User ID Site ID Transaction Type     Trans Date    Amount       
4   1   1   Sale    1/1/2017    120      1/1/2017  120
6   1   1   Refund  1/7/2017    -120     1/7/2017  -120
7   2   2   Sale    1/5/2017    90       1/5/2017  90 
9   2   1   Sale    12/1/2016   30       12/1/2016  30
10  2   1   Sale    1/1/2017    30       1/1/2017   30
11  2   1   Sale    2/1/2017    30       2/1/2017   30
12  2   1   Refund  2/7/2017    -30      2/7/2017   -30
```

Need to write a query that will return a table with the following columns

```
User ID, Site ID, User Name, Total Sales, Total Refunds, Net Amount Collected
```

Maybe I need a inner join function or some other join? I need another part of the join to get a table back with the right columns, Tried this but its only half i think.

```
with cte_sales as
(
    select
    t.[User Id],
    t.[Site Id],
    sum(t.Amount) as [Total Sales]
    from Transactions t
    where t.[Transaction Type] = 'Sale'
    group by t.[User Id],
             t.[Site Id]
),
cte_refunds as
(
    select
    t.[User Id],
    t.[Site Id],
    sum(t.Amount) as [Total Refunds]
    from Transactions t
    where t.[Transaction Type] = 'Refund'
    group by t.[User Id],
             t.[Site Id]
)

ith cte_sales as
(
    select
    t.[User Id],
    t.[Site Id],
    sum(t.Amount) as [Total Sales]
    from Transactions t
    where t.[Transaction Type] = 'Sale'
    group by t.[User Id],
             t.[Site Id]
),
cte_refunds as
(
    select
    t.[User Id],
    t.[Site Id],
    sum(t.Amount) as [Total Refunds]
    from Transactions t
    where t.[Transaction Type] = 'Refund'
    group by t.[User Id],
             t.[Site Id]
)
```

If i can get a table based on one single query with the columns described that would be awesome but currently brushing up on my joins.

Comment: Somehow my trans id and amount title columns were over extended but the last two value columns correspond with the titles mentioned.

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using. Is this sql-server? ms-access?

Comment: MYSQL sorry is the database sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join both tables and use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT
    u.[User ID],
    u.[Site ID],
    u.Name as [User Name],
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.[Transaction Type] = 'Sale'   THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.[Transaction Type] = 'Refund' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Refunds],
    SUM(t.Amount) AS [Net Amount Collected]
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Transactions t
    ON t.[User ID] = u.[User ID] AND t.[Site ID] = u.[Site ID]
GROUP BY
    u.[User ID],
    u.[Site ID],
    u.Name
```

Comment: Ah very interesting.